# Why Angular2 material generated "mat-card-header-text" and how to remove it's default height?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is there a reason why Angular2 material generated this `mat-card-header-text` around `md-header` and how to prevent it to have `height:40px;`?
It basically generates

```
<md-card-header ><div class="mat-card-header-text"><md-card-title ...
```

and the height of the `mat-card-header-text` is always 40px.

note : `mat-card-header-text` is generated after the css loaded, so, apply css style to the class will not affect anything. I hope to get answer and explanation from the angular2 perspective.

Answer (score 1):

in your **.css** file you should overwrite this tag,

```css
.mat-card-header-text{
  height: 200px !important;

 /* try this but I'm not sure if it works */
 height: auto !important;
 /* If you want this to work, parent should have a flexible height! */
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my question, I mean the `mat-card-header-text`. And, what if I want a flexible height?

Comment: I have tried this but it does not work, because `mat-card-header-text` is generated after css loaded, so the css is not affecting the class